# I can't set weight in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gridlayout

I've tried enough, searched the internet and I do not know what I can do to fix this.

I have in my code this:

```js
  <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:background="#f11"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Button"/>




    </GridLayout>
```

**In my IDE (ANDROID STUDIO 3.0) appear this: (Which is what I want.)**

[image]

**But in devices appear like this:**

[image]

**How fix this?**
Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `android:layout_height="0dp"` to Buttons

Comment: Hi @Gokhan Arik, thanks for answer. I tried, but doesn't work. Appear just 2 buttons on the entire screen.

Comment: What is parent of GridLayout? Do you have only 4 items? IT looks fine on my device.

Comment: Try to change `android:layout_rowWeight` for the bottom buttons!

Comment: Could you check my answer?@LuísBalmant

Comment: @KeLiuyue, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When android api <21 ,it didn't work well.

So we can add compile.

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
```

And change your xml code to this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f11"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_row="1"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

**Note**

In the `com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1`

It had new attribute.

- app:layout_columnWeight
- app:layout_rowWeight
- app:layout_rowSpan
- app:layout_columnSpan

You can use in your code.

Comment: Fast forward to 2020, `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'` has changed to `implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'` and `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` to `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use table format and assign the buttons in there easily which will cause no problem in various screens when compiled.